# Leaflet Offline Map: How to store a map for offline usage?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I want to save an OSM map with specific boundaries for offline usage in my file system without any DB outside of the web browser. After that I want to render the map with Leaflet library while offline. Is that possible?

Comment: This depends on your definition of "database". I guess you consider IndexedDB and related technologies (PouchDB *et al*) to be databases, but are `LocalStorage` and a `ServiceWorker`'s `Cache` databases?

Comment: In fact, I was talking about PostgreSQL or any other DB. IndexedDB would be OK for me.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this may be an XY problem, where saving tiles in cache of the web browser from an external provider sounds like only one of many possible solutions for the initial objective of offline usage, and not having to use (or actually not to *install*?) a database on client side.

If that is the case, @IvanSanchez's [Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles plugin](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles) *could* fit the bill: while the mbtiles file is technically a database, it is contained in a single portable file without requiring installation (it is an SQLite file).

The size could be over a browser cache, but if you have some control on the client, you can just copy it on file system. Then you can have your HTML page opened from file system as well, or a local server, which would also be more inline with offline usage.

Answer (score 2):

I see two main approaches for this:

1. Using [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), [`WebSQL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database), [Web Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) and/or related in-browser databases.

   From what I've seen, most developers prefer to rely on a library that wraps these technologies to offer consistent support across browsers (since not all browsers support all these technologies). Let me quote [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API#See_also):

   > Note: IndexedDB API is powerful, but may seem too complicated for simple cases. If you'd prefer a simple API, try libraries such as localForage, dexie.js, ZangoDB, PouchDB, idb, idb-keyval, JsStore and lovefield that make IndexedDB more programmer-friendly.

   In particular, an [implementation of a PouchDB-backed Leaflet Tilelayer](https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.TileLayer.PouchDBCached) is available; but don't lat this prevent you from exploring other options.
2. Using [`ServiceWorker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)s ability to store things on a browser's [`Cache`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache).

   A `ServiceWorker` is able to capture *all* network requests that a webpage makes, including tiles (even if the tileservers reside on a different domain name). Then, one can apply the [known `ServiceWorker`-based caching techniques](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/). After that, it should be even possible to send messages to the `ServiceWorker` to seed the cache (or just make enough `fetch` requests for the tiles).

   I'm not aware (at the time of this writing) of any straightforward Leaflet integrations. Implementation involves creating a [manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) to point to the JS file with the `ServiceWorker` code, and an implementation of a [cache mechanism](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/#cache-falling-back-to-network).

Comment: If I store the map data in PouchDB on server side, is there any possibility that my data would be deleted after some time? I would like to have a persistent storage.

Comment: @fatma.ekici: you might be confusing things in the Client-Server architecture, making it difficult to help you with the level of explanations you may need. Sounds to me like you should rethink first what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am a C++ programmer and I don't have any Javascript and web prog. experience. The thing that I want to achieve is to provide a high quality Leaflet map to a user who doesn't have any Internet access. We will have a local network with a server where we run Leaflet app. and several users in the same network connecting to that application.

Comment: Then this just got upgraded to a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), with [mapproxy](https://mapproxy.org/) (or other LAN-hosted service) being a potential solution to the root problem.

Comment: @IvanSanchez I am using your MBTiles plugin. I've just wondered if there is an upper limit for the size of the mbtiles file. I had a file with 300GB size from ESRI and could not render it.